# Use webcam to track eyes to switch monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, webcam

I use a dual monitor set-up, where I have one main application on the left monitor and another on the right monitor. I switch between the two monitors very often (probably once per minute) using alt+tab. While it works just fine 95% of the time, I sometimes mess it up by forgetting which window I was using or by simply beginning to type in, not realizing that I did not press Alt+Tab. In these cases, I wish the computer *knew* where I was looking when typing so I did not have to switch manually. Do you know if there any way to do this using my webcam? Or is a webcam too low-res / too 2D or the technology not there yet?

I tried looking it up but did not find anything besides a Stanford paper ( http://hci.stanford.edu/cstr/reports/2007-02.pdf ).

Comment: I've removed your greetings (there's a reason the site won't allow it! Its not how we do things here!), and did a few other edits to make it more of a "How do i solve a problem" question than a software rec.

Comment: Okay, thanks! It's my first time posting, I don't know all the rules yet, and on most forums, asking a question without greetings is a big no-no, and I just thought it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now you are not gonna find just some software that makes your webcam scan your eyes in other to select different windows. You can in fact control your mouse with headtracking and a webcam but its gonna be much slower than reaching for the mouse, it's used for people with disabilities.
What kind of workflow do you have? Typing alot? Any disability?
It depends on the application but you could use a ring mouse while typing or even an touchpad just below the keyboard.